# PHP, FTP and source control system

Tags: php, git, svn, version-control, ftp

In our team of programmers we are looking for a way to improve our work by implementing version control.

We currently use tortoise SVN, it's convenient, but still leaves some points unmanaged

For example: We need to modify some .php scripts (we do it with notepad ++) of the example.com website, in the tortoise SVN repository we create a new folder and modify the files, then with filezilla we transfer the modified files inside the ftp of example.com

Is there a way to combine the two? edit script php + ftp transfer?

Considering that we have more than one site under management and all of them obviously rely on an ftp server which should mirror the production repository created.

What solution could we adopt?

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you need some sort of continuous delivery platform

Comment: Why don't you check out the repository on the server? No need to use FTP.

Comment: Both actions (edit/transfer to production) in a single shot sounds like you are skipping a lot of steps. No code review? No testing (at least running unit tests)? Those are steps you _should_ implement before you deploy something in production.

Comment: @eftshift0 that is correct, we are currently testing the code on a clone test directory of the website being edited. How could I improve the production process so that everything is well tracked?

Comment: My personal take? Switch to git, and implement CI/CD :-D. But just those 2 things involve _a lot_ of things to happen from the point you are to the ultimate goal of.... well, everlasting developer happiness.

Comment: @eftshift0 I don't want to complicate the process much, now making a change is fast (take the necessary file and re-upload it) but it does not allow me to understand what the other team members have really worked on at the end of the day

Comment: I would be willing to go as far as to advice that you work on finding ways to improve your workflows. I know that svn is not as flexible as git (which might make finding workflows tricky, IMHO) but you should be able to see what other developers/teams do with svn. Simple question: Do you merge back changes from the _branch_ once development of a feature is finished? One simple thing would be to deploy from there instead of the separate branches.... but that is, if all sites that you support are kept on the same release.

Comment: @eftshift0 Currently we don't even use branches, we create new folders inside the repository which contains all the subfolders of the sity, for example repall / example1.com, repall / example2.com etc ...
subsequently inside each folder we create a new one with the date of the day, for example 2021-07-21 where we transfer only the scripts to be edited.

Next we commit that, in short it is all disconnected from the branch

Comment: well, well... sounds like a recipe for disaster, quite frankly. Why do you do it this way (feel free to explain with more details in the original question so we all get a better idea of what is going on... examples are welcome)? I don't see why you would want to copy stuff into a different folder in the same branch to do an adjustment on a file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to have a script that deploys your changes, say, `script/deploy` in the repository, possibly with an argument to specify the site or sites to deploy.  When you've made the change and you're ready to deploy, either run that command yourself, or have an automated system run it.  The latter can be implemented if you have some sort of way to automatically run code when it's being merged to the trunk (or main branch in Git).  Having an automated system do it is better if you have shared credentials because you don't want to check them into the repository (since that's insecure) and you'll need a secure place to store them.

With Git, you could perform a `git diff --name-only` between the old and new revisions to find which directories (and hence which sites) had been changed, and deploy only those.  I'm not sure how to do that with SVN, but there's probably a way.

There are of course a variety of CI/CD systems that will handle this for you and allow you to script it efficiently, plus provide a safe way to store credentials and inject them using the environment.  They can also run any automated tests you have, and you may wish to have code review.  The CI/CD system can also check to see if these requirements are met before deploying.

I should point out that in general, using FTP is not a great idea, since it's practically difficult to use TLS with it (due to many broken implementations) and it's not really responsible to deploy code over an unencrypted connection, since anybody can tamper with it.  SFTP may be available in your environment, and if so, it would be more secure; if not, definitely verify that TLS is correctly configured to handle both the control and data connections.

Comment: rsync (through ssh) might also be a tool to consider in order to sync up.